# What is Flash's timeout (TTL) when loading variables? AS2

Tags: flash, load, timeout, actionscript-2, loading

I have a Flash AS 2 project.. it loads variables using the myData.load(link) function..during this loading period i have a "please wait" animation....   when data is it turns off this waiting animation and runs my routine ..

all is well.

but my problem is if this myData.load() TIMES OUT.. meaning if FLASH tries to load the variables when the internet is down , the waiting animation stays forever.. even when i reconnect to the internet already, flash seems to get stuck at that loading sequence..

now, i can simply fix this by putting a "timeout" on the waiting animation to turn off after a few seconds.. that is in sync when flash decides to stop sending/loading the variables (Time To Live/Time Out kind of thing).. hence i need to know how long flash waits, and how to detect it.

I hope flash can detect this time out, trigger my load function w/ a fail status at least .. w/ the obsolete loadVariables() function this is better coz atleast flash responds FAIL when it cant connect to the target URL..

This also avoids several problems for me when that function is re-called.

any ideas?

Comment: Not sure about AS2 but if you're willing to move to AS3 you can utilise many events that are fired when your script times out or fails for a multitude of other reasons.

Comment: thanks marty.. unfortunately i dont see myself moving to AS3 anytime soon. i've been planning to but i just have sooo many projects deployed already and being maintained using AS2 and I havent had anytime to learn the darn thing.. ... specially since everything i need to do i can do already w/ AS2 w/c i find faster too in development.. except for a few minor quirks such as this in question.. so i guess i'm stuck w/ doing a workaround..